# dynamically creating a multiple nested div with image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I want to add multiple times 2 nested div and an image inside a div with id 'owl-demo'.

I wrote the following code:

```
 var imgsrc = '';
$.each(data , function(key , value) {                                                   
var itemDiv = $("<div class='item'  onclick=getItem(prodId)>")
                .append( $("<div class='cau_lef' id='hill'> "))
                .append( $("<img class='lazyOwl'  alt='Lazy Owl Image' />" ).attr('src',imgsrc));

 $("#owl-demo").append(itemDiv);    
});
```

> The HTML CODE IS AS FOLLOW:-

```
  <div class="main_bg1">
       <div class="wrap">   
          <div class="main1" >
               <h2 id="category2"> </h2>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrap">
      <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
      </div>
   </div>
```

> Although I aam getting no Js error, I am also not getting any output.
>   please help me with it. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Sure looks like an error to me, you have a semicolon ending the second line

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/qL52s0re/

Comment: This works perfectly fine in loop also. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qL52s0re/3/

Comment: Hmm.. works fine here... Thanks... But I don't know why yet I can't get it in my files.... But thanks.. at least I know I'm on right track..

Comment: Glad to help R.K. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove **;** character from end of second line:

```
var itemDiv = $("<div class='item'  onclick=getItem(prodId)>")
                .append( $("<div class='cau_lef' id='hill'> "))
                .append( $("<img src='" + imgsrc + "' class='lazyOwl'  alt='Lazy Owl Image' />" )));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjqckyLu/)

Comment: No... yet didn't get the output

Comment: `attr` method doesn't return a  html element. Put `src` attribute into tag.

Comment: if i add src into tag, I get file error...While when i use attr , the image file is found.. However In both the cases it should have at least displayed the alternate text... But it doesn't

Comment: @SiamakFerdos this also works , check out adeneo's fiddle in question's comments. or this: http://jsfiddle.net/qL52s0re/1/

Comment: Works with one image but not when added in a loop

Answer (score -2):

Put your js code or files in bottom.
Data in foreach is undefined. Y are u using data?

Comment: Then he must got an error. He said he is not getting any JS errors.

Comment: That's the data from server... And I am getting values in that loop correctly.. However the div & image are not displayed.

Comment: & I have to display multiple nested div with image, so require a loop